# Why upper bound in Class is not allowed?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Why can't we have the following type of class in JAVA?

```
public class MyType<T super Integer> {
}
```

Comment: `Integer` may be a bad example to pick, since it's a `final` class, so it can't be the superclass of anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it has nothing to do with the question!

Comment: @snr - Please re-read my comment. The point is: Let's not distract from the question with a bad example.